# « Pick your battles » : le conseil et le choix de ?

Tags: sens, expressions, anglais

Dernièrement je me suis entendu utiliser une expression que je croyais (sans doute [à tort](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick%20your%20battles%2Cchoose%20your%20battles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpick%20your%20battles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchoose%20your%20battles%3B%2Cc0)) fort courante et ancienne en langue anglaise, le « pick your battles » ([*pick one's battles*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pick+your+battles)), qu'on entend semble-t-il par le fait de ne pas faire un combat de la moindre situation pour plutôt conserver son énergie en vue du moment opportun où prendre position serait plus significatif. On donne un exemple où un parent apprend à « pick your battles » avec ses enfants pour ne pas avoir à leur faire des remontrances à chaque bout de champ. Je vois bien que c'est *choisir*, qu'il y a le *possessif*, les batailles, les combats, les sorties, etc.

J'ai utilisé l'expression pour signifier à une personne qu'elle dépensait beaucoup d'énergie alors qu'une situation ne semblait pas vraiment le justifier (on nous sert un café froid au restaurant et on envisage le recours collectif), tel le sens en anglais. Je l'ai aussi utilisée pour en faire l'apologie et indiquer qu'une situation représentait bien le moment opportun et qu'on agissait ainsi donc en conséquence, et donc qu'on « signe ».

---

Comment rend-on en français l'emploi de la locution dans les deux cas de manière **courante** ?

> On donne un conseil à quelqu'un : « [pick your battles] ».
>  On informe quelqu'un de l'aspect volontaire de sa position : « on dit souvent [pick your
>   battles], et c'est ce que je fais ».

Comment: Personnellement, j'ai déjà entendu "Choisis tes batailles", mais je pense que simplement que ce n'est pas une expression très connue. Ca ne m'étonnerait pas de devoir l'expliquer si je l'utilise.

Comment: On utilise communément l'expression "choisir ses combats".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour moi, les personnes qui croient (et conseillent)  qu’il faut savoir choisir “one’s battles” sont souvent celles qui croient aussi qu’il est important de [re]garder le «big picture», ou au moins de le considérer.

Je crois que «la/une vue d’ensemble» peut capter la notion de «the big picture» et j’ai trouvé [cet exemple de ‘Google Books’](https://books.google.com/books?id=SxM0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&dq=%22garder+une+vue+d%27ensemble%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD7femkZPLAhUT6mMKHTdsB4UQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22garder%20une%20vue%20d%27ensemble%22&f=false) qui emploie «garder une vue d’ensemble» dans ce sens :

> La capacité à garder une vue d’ensemble (big picture) … .

Je ne sais pas si «verbe + la/une vue d’ensemble» est idiomatique en Français pour capter «keep the big picture in mind» (qui, encore, pour moi = «pick your battles»), et même si c'est le cas, je ne saurait pas quel verbe choisir: («regarder la …/garder une …/considérer la …»?), mais pour conseiller quelqu'un ou offrir une justification pour «backing down» dans vos contextes, je crois que je dirais quelque chose comme:

> Regardez/regardons la vue d’ensemble.
>
> Des fois [comme maintenant] il vaut mieux considérer la vue
>   d’ensemble.

(Feeling incapable of making the following edit in proper French, I've resorted to doing it in English, sorry):

While confirming that the good suggestion (now a good answer) made in a comment below was idiomatic, I ran across an expression that might also be appropriate, especially in the advice-giving context presented in the question {and to a lesser extent [using the imperfect or conditional] in the reason-giving one}:

> {J’ai signé car} D’après moi [le jeu ne vaut/{valait/vaudrait} pas la
>   chandelle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/le_jeu_ne_vaut_pas_la_chandelle)

Here the “jeu” could be the “battle [not worth fighting]” and the “chandelle” could be the "energy [not worth expending/worth conserving]."

Comment: Je pense que "prendre du recul" rejoint un peu ça aussi, non ?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oui, tout à fait! Pas seulement pour capter plus idiomatiquement "consider the big picture" que ma réponse, mais aussi, d'après moi, pour capter plus directement (même pas besoin de passer par "the big picture") la notion de "l'action" associée avec "picking one's battles" (all that to say that it’s answer-worthy, imo).

Comment: Ok, je poste une réponse alors.

Comment: Thank you! That transposing of the idiom to the big picture one, is that because you feel the idiom is somewhat weak or not fully expressive or something? The idiom doesn't seem to exist before the '70-80s, but this is off topic. In French I believe _looking at the big picture_ can be further abstracted to an idea such as being more "_pragmatique_". Otherwise le _jeu qui n'en vaut pas la chandelle_ is very idiomatic imho and useful, especially for sort of lecturing someone and I've heard it in such contexts indeed, and how you read the expression is perfectly in line with that.

Comment: Thanks@comet ! Why I got there in English IS off-topic but it's from the frustration I feel when administrators(paid to see&deal w/the big picture) tell my French-middle-school-teaching wife(paid to advocate for&teach to her tiny part of the collage) that SHE "must see the big picture & choose her battles accordingly" when asking why teachers (& therefore their students) of Carnegie-Unit/High-School-level language courses are made to suffer traveling on carts between 5 classrooms & in cars between 2+ schools while those of regular(non-Carnegie-Unit), albeit “core” middle school courses aren't!

Answer (score 2):

Pour compléter la réponse de Papa Poule, dans l'optique de "garder une vue d'ensemble", on peut aussi parler de **prendre du recul**, la définition pertinente de [recul](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/recul) étant:

> Temps nécessaire à une appréciation globale ou à une meilleure appréciation d'un événement.

Prendre du recul, c'est prendre le temps de regarder la situation dans son ensemble, et de se rendre compte qu'il vaut peut-être mieux choisir une autre bataille qui en vaudrait plus la peine.

*You should learn to pick your battle*: Il faut que tu apprennes à prendre du recul.

Comment: Merci ! Donc l'idée de la _prudence_ plutôt que le pragmatisme si je comprends bien ? Si on s'apprête à livrer une bataille et qu'on fait le constat qu'on a pris le recul et qu'on passe à l'action, comme en deuxième exemple, peut-on simplement ajouter l'idée de négation à _prendre du recul_, c.-à-d. ne plus, terminé, etc.. ?

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire qu'il faut "choisir son moment" ou "attendre son heure".
Cela semble fonctionner pour vos deux acceptions :

> Ne t'emballe pas, attend ton heure !
>
> Alors toi, tu sais choisir ton moment.

À chaque fois, l'action est sous entendue.

Comment: Je pense qu'il n'y a pas la même connotation. Avec ces 2 formulation, on dit juste de faire l'action plus tard. Alors que "Pick your battle" signifie plûtot « laisse tomber, ça vaut pas le coup de te battre pour ça, garde ton énergie pour un vrai problème »...

Comment: Merci ! _Attendre son heure_, ce ne serait pas une référence à l'_heure de gloire_ et est-ce que ça marche ici ? Dans le 2e exemple je m'exprime sans doute mal, c'est la personne qui a choisi son moment qui indique l'avoir en effet choisi, je voulais indiquer avec les crochets que _ce que j'ai fait_ était sous-entendu mais c'est une affirmation. Je vais corriger.

Answer (score 1):

> Garde ton calme
>
> Laisse tomber
>
> Cela ne vaut pas la peine de s'énerver

Plus familièrement

> Arrête ton char

Comment: Merci ! Ne pas valoir la peine, donc l'_utilité_. _Arrête ton char_, impayable, vu que ça aurait un sens différent pour moi ; curieusement je pourrais utiliser _chiard_ pour obtenir un sens voisin du vôtre je crois, autrement je pense à arrêter la voiture avant le précipice ou je ne sais !

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Dans l’hexagone, un *chiard* (du pure argot, de chiant) est un enfant braillard, pénible. Rien à voir avec le *char* de Ben-Hur : on dit souvent arrête ton *char* Ben-Hur la course est finie/'y a pas d'course aujourd'hui/t'arrive trop tard/t'attaques la falaise...

Comment: Merci de préciser, j'avais complètement manqué la référence à Ben-Hur !

Answer (score 1):

En suivant la piste offerte dans la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17933) et les autres contributions, on peut aussi penser à l'idée de *pragmatisme*, mais surtout de l'adjectif en attribut, [*pragmatique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pragmatique), pour « [En parlant d'une pers.] [q]ui est plus soucieux de l'action, de la réussite de l'action que de considérations théoriques ou idéologiques. » (*TLFi*) On en a un indice, et à mon avis couramment ça s'oppose à l'[*idéalisme*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/id%C3%A9alisme) ([*idéaliste*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/id%C3%A9aliste), adj.) pour la recherche de l'idéal. [*Se montrer diplomate*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diplomate) (*TLFi* : « Synon. (partiels) adroit, astucieux, circonspect, habile, rusé, souple, subtil. ») est possiblement différent. Il peut y avoir des éclairages différents de l'expression présentée en question selon qu'on observe sous l'angle du pragmatisme, de la prudence, ou généralement de l'utilité. L'alternative *pragmatique/idéaliste* (en substantif) me semble la plus juste.

---

> — Tu devrais être plus pragmatique...
>   — C'est l'idéaliste qui... [s'exprime, parle, agit
>   ici].